# javascript (es6) return value of filter in forEach

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have function like below.

If the value of the filter is an array with more than 4 I want to return just the key.

For instance `const result = gethitedShips(); // result be 1 or 2` but I get `undefined`

I totally got confused where to return what

```
    getHitShips = () => {
    const { players } = this.props;
    return Object.keys(players).forEach(key => {
      const hitShips = players[key].ships.filter(ship => ship.health <= 0);
      if (hitShips.length >= 5) return key;
      return null;
    });
  };
```

Comment: it is not undefined more, but returns an array with the length of Object.keys (now all of them null)

Comment: @PouyaJabbarisani What?

Comment: You'r returning `key` inside forEach function. it won't be affected on your outer function. unless you store it in a variable then return it in outer function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could filter the keys by checking the length

```
const getHitedShips = () => {
    const { players } = this.props;
    return Object
        .keys(players)
        .filter(key => players[key].ships.filter(ship => ship.health <= 0).length >= 5);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Coming from Java, this is o confusing for me:)